# How to access Closure properties from inside closure code?

Tags: groovy, scope, closures

I'm banging my head against this wall for more than a week now, let me explain briefly what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a DSL defined like this (brief example)

```
TestingSpec
    .newInstance()
    .sayHello()   --> print "Hello "+something
    .sayGoddbye() --> print "Goddbye"+something
```

Note the `something` in there that is not passed anywhere intentionally, because I want to limit the scope of use of my DSL by the will be users, so what I actually want is to somehow "inject" the `something` in that DSL instance programmatically. This is being done by using a Closure.

```
Myscript.execute( {
    TestingSpec
        .newInstance()
        .sayHello()   --> print "Hello "+something
        .sayGoddbye() --> print "Goddbye"+something 
})
```

and `MyScript` will invoke it by passing the `something` value to it, either by passing a parameter, or by adding a property or by adding a Binding (don't know what's the best, really)

```
close.call("Toni")

close.metaClass.something = "Toni"

def binding = new Binding()
binding.setVariable("something", "Toni")
close.setBinding(binding)
```

But now I'm stuck in what I thought it was going to be easy, how from the TestingSpec code can I access the Closure `something`? For instance

```
public newInstance() {
    def instance = new TestingSpec()
    instance.something = *MY CLOSURE SOMETHING*
    return instance
}
```

I've tried several options, like messing with the `this`, `owner` and `delegate` of the closure, but couldn't do it.

Any hint will be very welcome...

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's doable. `TestingSpec` is too high on the stack to be aware he is being invoked from a closure. I'd like to suggest two solutions

**1. Pass `something` to `TestingSpec` programmatically.**

```
Myscript.execute( {
    TestingSpec
        .newInstance(something)
        .sayHello()   --> print "Hello "+something
        .sayGoddbye() --> print "Goddbye"+something 
})
```

**2. Make the `TestingSpec` instance be created by `MyScript`**

I like this solution more. It is about `MyScript.execute({})` being responsible for creating and handling the lifecycle of `TestingSpec`:

```
class TestingSpec {
    def something
    def sayHello() {
        println "Hello " + something
        this
    }
    def sayGoddbye() {
        println "Goddbye " + something
        this
    }
}

class Myscript {
    static TestingSpec testingSpec
    static execute(closure) {
        def binding = new Binding(something: 'test for echo')
        testingSpec = new TestingSpec(something: binding.something)
        binding.testingSpec = testingSpec
        closure.binding = binding
        closure()
    }
}

Myscript.execute( {
    testingSpec // this is an instance, and not a static call
        .sayHello()   // print "Hello "+something
        .sayGoddbye() // print "Goddbye"+something 
})
```

Output:

```
$ groovy Spec.groovy 
Hello test for echo
Goddbye test for echo
```

**3. Delegate the closure to `testingSpec`**

If you set the closure delegate to `testingSpec`, you can invoke its methods without referencing `testingSpec` directly, providing a very clean code. Note i also updated the example to remove `MyScript`:

```
class TestingSpec {
    static TestingSpec testingSpec
    static execute(closure) {
        def binding = new Binding(something: 'test for echo')
        testingSpec = new TestingSpec(something: binding.something)
        binding.testingSpec = testingSpec
        closure.delegate = testingSpec
        closure.binding = binding
        closure()
    }

    def something
    def sayHello() {
        println "Hello " + something
        this
    }
    def sayGoddbye() {
        println "Goddbye " + something
        this
    }

}

TestingSpec.execute( {
    sayHello()   // print "Hello "+something
    sayGoddbye() // print "Goddbye"+something 
})
```

**4. Inject `testingSpec` as a parameter into your closure**

As per your answer, a simple suggestion: consider giving a `testingSpec` var that you've built yourself to the user, since it allows more control and customization to you. Think a simple inversion of control (this allows `testingSpec` to see dynamic variables in the closure's binding):

```
.withDistinctNames({ testingSpec ->
    testingSpec
        .from(name)
        .withAddress(email) 
        .sendEmail(template) 
})
```

With a full test:

```
class TestingSpec {
    def commands = []
    static newInstance(listOfNames) {
        new TestingSpec()
    }

    def sayHello() { commands << "sayHello"; this }
    def waveGoddbye() { commands << "waveGoddbye"; this }
    def withAddress(address) { commands << "withAddress $address"; this }
    def sendEmail(template) { commands << "sendEmail $template"; this }

    def withDistinctNames(closure) {
        commands << "withDistinctNames"
        closure.binding = new Binding(address: "sunset boulevard", template: 'email is $email')
        closure(this)
        this
    }
}

test = TestingSpec
    .newInstance([:])
    .sayHello()
    .withDistinctNames({ me ->
        me
            .withAddress(address)
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
    .waveGoddbye()

assert test.commands == [
    'sayHello', 
    'withDistinctNames', 
    'withAddress sunset boulevard', 
    'sendEmail email is $email', 
    'waveGoddbye'
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The 1st solution is what I'm doing now but trying to avoid, I'm using the `close.call("Toni")` and referring it like `TestingSpec.newInstance(it)`. The 2nd solution I did not think about it, I'm afraid it will be more complicated because in my "real" scenario both Myscript and TestingSpec  are the same. The idea is actually to pass a parameter from the outer TestingSpec to the inner (in the closure) TestingSpec . I'm going to try now.

Comment: @amsmota Having `TestingSpec` and `MyScript` as the same class is not a problem for the second solution, i wrote a third solution featuring both as the same class and with closure delegation. Also, consider accepting some answers in your previously asked questions.

Comment: Hi @WillP, thanks again for your suggestions. I'm afraid I didn't explain myself correctly, basically because I'm a newbie in Groovy. So I shouldn't have use the word "script" like in MyScript, because this are classes that will be invoked from Java and not groovy scripts. So (and I only figured this out later) I can't use the Binding option. However your suggestions 1 and 3 made me put out a solution that is not ideal but it's "elegant" enough and "easy" to understand by would-be users of my DSL, I'll put it as a answer to my question.

Comment: In relation to accepting answers in my previously asked questions, believe or not but I've been meaning to do it but I'm so overflown with work that it's been always on the bottom of my to-do list, I'll try to do it asap. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally reach a solution to my problem that while not ideal it's "elegant" enough and "easy" to understand by would-be users of my DSL. So, what I want to do is allow the DSL users to write things like this:

```
TestingSpec
    .newInstance()
    .from(listOfNames)
    .sayHello()
    .withDistinctNames({
        TestingSpec
            .newInstance()
            .from(*****) <---- problem
            .withAddress()
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
    .waveGoddbye()
```

There could be a number of *with* methods that basically serve as a filter+loop, so in this example it will filter the names to be unique and then apply the Closure to each name in turn. Of course this would be extremely easy to do by just doing

```
    .withDistinctNames({
        TestingSpec
            .newInstance()
            .from(it)
            .withAddress()
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
```

or for more complicated cases

```
    .withDistinctNames({ name, email, template ->
        TestingSpec
            .newInstance()
            .from(name)
            .withAddress(email)
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
```

The prob is I don't know who is going to use this DSL, it may not be people familiar with closures, parameters, functions, whatnots, it may be people even from outside my organization, so my goal was to keep it simple by passing the needed variables from the outer Spec to the inner Spec. In my TestingSpec implementation I would have:

```
public TestingSpec withAll(Closure k, Closure f) { // withAll is used by all with* methods
    def result = k.call(root) // root is the entire listOfNames
    def results = result
        .collect {
            // HERE'S THE PROBLEM, HOW TO INJECT ALL THE PARAMETERS INTO THE INNER SPEC?
            f.call(it) // this line passes vars to the Closure, not the inner Spec, and I found no way for the Closure itself to inject them in the Spec
        }
    return this;
}
```

After I saw it was impossible to inject params in the inner Spec itself (that is yet to be instantiated) I tried to pass them to the Closure and from there to the Spec, like this:

```
    .withDistinctNames({
        TestingSpec
            .newInstance()
            .from(this) <-------------------
            .withAddress()
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
```

I supposed that *this* would be the outer Spec that contains all the info I need, but it was not. I tried with *this*, *this.thisObject*, *this.owner*, *this.delegate*.

But then, with the help of the 3rd above suggestion I ended up doing this:

```
public TestingSpec withAll(Closure k, Closure f) {

    f = f.rehydrate(f.getDelegate(), f.getOwner(), this)

    def result = k.call(root) 
    def results = result
        .collect {
            this.parameters = [whatever I need]
            f.call() 
        }
    return this;
}
```

This way the *this* in the DSL is actually the outer Spec, so the users can now use the more intuitive "this" keyword. To avoid confusion I got rid of the *.from()* method, like this:

```
TestingSpec
    .newInstance(listOfNames)
    .sayHello()
    .withDistinctNames({
        TestingSpec
            .newInstance(this) // my newInstance implementation can parse all the parameters as it wishes
            .withAddress()
            .sendEmail(template)        
    })
    .waveGoddbye()
```

While it's not ideal is close enough, from the perspective of the potential users, I think. If somebody has suggestions please let me know.

Thanks Will P and all.

Comment: Wow! That is huge! I'm glad you found a solution! I've updated my answer with one more suggestion. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After  working on a small similar Groovy DSL tool recently and digging a bit into griffon and swing and other material I currently ended with the following, that I submit as another suggestion to the answer.
Any comment/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

---

IMHO a clear separation between the domain model (a **Model** class) , and the support classes (building, aggregation , context sharing, and filtering part of the model, at least  a **Builder** class) is one of the key elements
to have a simple and efficient model. This is the pattern used in groovy swing and griffon and showed to be very flexible.

It allows constructs with **each {}**, **with {}** and **collection operations** which are clean and understandable enough,
and mostly without chaining operations (ie adding an annoying  **return this** at the end of each operation).

Like here for example (source code at the end, **MSys** is a Facade to the underlying system):

```
MSys.with {
        model.each {
            it.sayHello
            it.sayGoodBye
            it.setAddress randomAddress(it.name);
            it.sendEmail
        }

        println " Hello counts"
        model.each {
            def key = it.name
            def value = MSys.context[key]
            println "Counter for ${key} = ${value}"
        }
    }
```

or

```
MSys.model.each {
        it.with {
            sayHello
            sayGoodBye
            setAddress  randomAddress(name) ;
            sendEmail
        }
    }
```

or

```
MSys.eachModelDo {
        sayHello
        sayGoodBye
        setAddress randomAddress(it.name);
        sendEmail
    }
```

or ... 
(lot of possibilities)

It also allows to have some shared context very easily (in the example , **context** is a Map shared between all the Model elements where almost anything could be put, connection information, user preferences, cache etc.),
and to hide all the boiler plate to the user by putting it in another class/script .

The responsibilities would be :

- **SpecModel** : Domain model : say hello, goodbye, properties etc
- **SpecBuilder** : creates models (from a list in the example), holds shared context (a map) and eventually take care of the closure delegate context for some operations

This separation is important to deal with **set operations**  on one side and  **entity (model) operations** on the other. 
Apart from beeing a builder, from a user POV it is a facade

and from a developer POV BTW it should be a Facade to several classes including the builder -but better start simple.

The next step would be to integrate FactoryBuilderSupport in this builder in order to benefit from Groovy DSL builder facilities, but this one big step beyond and I'm not comfortable with that yet ... (WIP right now)

---

Few Groovy recaps that you certainly already know but part of the problem if you want a light syntax :

- In Groovy  **,** , **;** and  **()** are  optional except when there is a conflict.

Even where there is no direct conflict, the delegation strategy is not always direct and 
run time errors are not always clear  (see link on closures doc below)

- Having a public getter method for properties, allows the use of property like access methods without the (),
  the get and set prefixes are inferred

ie with a method like

```
public getSendEmail() {
    println "email for ${name}"
}
```

you can use the syntax :

```
myObject sendEmail
```

Groovy assumes a property getter call and do the rest.
This helps removing the **()** in the dsl syntax.

- The context is the delegate context of the closure **it** not the **this**

When you use closures, you use **it** to reference the object you are working on in the closure
(ie the receiver of the message).

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3].each { println it }
```

is ok

If you haved used

```
[1, 2, 3].each { println this }
```

you would have print a reference to the outer object, the console in groovy console

(Which IIRC was one of the problem you had in your first post)

This is well explained in the [Groovy Closures](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) doc :

(excerpt:)

- **this** : the enclosing class where the closure is defined
- **owner** : the enclosing object where the closure is defined,  a class or a closure
- **delegate** : third party object where methods calls or properties are resolved whenever the receiver of the message is not defined

The **message delegation strategy** (explained in the same document) is not always direct and this was your real problem I think.

---

That said, another key point in a  DSL is the coherence from a  user POV.
This means  consistence in data access patterns and here the standard Groovy collections (**Lists**, **maps** **each{}** etc) can help a lot. 
Plus it can be **a huge plus for power users**.

Syntactic sugar methods like **eachModelDo** can easily be done on a builder/facade class:

```
MSys.eachModelDo {
        sayHello
        sayGoodBye
        setAddress randomAddress(it.name);
        sendEmail
    }
```

NB: eachModelDo is very simple but a bit tricky to debug

At one point it "worked" well without  accessing correct variables :(

I have the feeling that something is wrong here (?) or at least it should be improved (comments welcome)

```
/**
 *  syntactic sugar
 *  direct access without 'it' (optional)
 */
public SpecBuilder eachModelDo(closure) {
    model.each {
        closure.delegate = it;
        closure(it)
    }
}
```

---

Bellow is the source code of a small test I did that  you can cut and paste in a groovy console

The only part visible to the user should be the method **Demo.run()** 
All the other stuff should be hidden

Any comments are welcome

---

```
/**
 * The builder build Specs and defines utility methods, filters
 * It shares its context with all elements in the domain
 */
class SpecBuilder {
    /** the context will be shared with all domain model objects */
    private context
    /** model = all the domain model objects */
    private model

    /** getters / setters */
    public getModel() { return model }

    public getContext() {
        return context
    }

    /** constructors and helpers */
    public SpecBuilder(aContext) {
        context = aContext
    }
    /** Default constructor forbidden */
    private SpecBuilder() {}

    public from(aList, closure) {
        from(aList);
        model.each { closure(it) }
        return this
    }

    public from(aList) {
        model = aList.collect { new SpecModel(it, context) }
        return this
    }



    /* TODO filters etc */


    /** stats: print counters */
    public stats() {
        println " Hello counts"
        model.each {
            def key = it.name
            def value = this.context[key]
            println "Counter for ${key} = ${value}"
        }
    }
    /**
     *  syntactic sugar
     *  direct access without 'it' (optional)
     */
    public SpecBuilder eachModelDo(closure) {
        model.each {
            closure.delegate = it;
            closure(it)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The Spec Domain  Model
 */
class SpecModel {

    /** the shared context */
    private context;
    /** other properties */
    private name;
    public address;

    /** getters and setters */
    public getName() { return name }
    public void setAddress(a) { address = a }
    public getAddress() { return address }
    public sayHello() { return getSayHello }
    public sayGoodBye() { return getSayGoodBye }
    public sendEmail() { return getSendEmail }

    /** constructors */
    public SpecModel(aName, aContext) {
        name = aName
        context = aContext
    }

    /** Default constructor forbidden */
    private SpecModel() {}

    /**  method used like properties, without 'get' and ()*/
    public getSayHello() {
        println "(!) hello ${name}"
        context[name] = context.get(name,0) +1;
    }
    public getSayGoodBye() {
        println "goodBye ${name} !"
    }
    public getSendEmail() {
        println "email for ${name}"
        if (address)
            println "Address ${address}"
    }
    public getPrintContext() {
        println context
    }
    /**
     * Returns info to caller
     */
    public gatherInfo() {
        "info for ${name} : ${new java.util.Random().nextInt(50000)}"
    }


}

class Demo {

    // several Groots here to test uniques ...
    def customers = ['Groot', 'Gamora', 'Groot', 'Groot', 'Groot', 'Star-Lord']

    /**
     * Utility function who generates a random address
     * @param name will prefix the address
     * @return the address
     */
    public randomAddress(def name) {
        // good places ... :)
        def places = [
                "Grande Rue",
                "Cours Emile Zola",
                "Place Antonin Poncet",
                "Rue de la République",
                "Boulevard de la Croix Rousse",
                "Place Bellecour"
        ]
        def random = new java.util.Random();
        return  new StringBuilder().append(name).append(" ... ")
                        // why not 42?
                        .append( random.nextInt(155)).append("  ")
                        .append( places[random.nextInt(places.size())] )
                .toString();
    }

    /**
     * ======================== Main user program =========================
     */
    def run() {
        /**  the shared context */
        def context = [:].asSynchronized() // In case of multi threading access

        /** The whole system From a user POV : a big façade */
        def MSys = new SpecBuilder(context).from(customers) ;


        println "*** 1 ==================== "
        /** First form */
        MSys.model.each {
            it.with {
                sayHello
                sayGoodBye
                setAddress  randomAddress(name) ;
                sendEmail
            }
        }
        /** other forms
         * MSys.with{  is handy
         * one could write MSys... on each line
         */
        MSys.with {

            println "*** 2 ==================== "
            model.each { it.sayHello };

            println "*** 3 ==================== "
            model.with { println " a Model entry = ${it.name} + ${it.address}" }

            println "*** 4 ==================== "
            /** false not to mutate the model !!! */
            model.unique(false, { a, b -> a.name <=> b.name }).each { it.sayHello }

            println "*** 5 ==================== "
            context['aKey'] = 42
            // verify that each entity has the same context
            model.with { println " a shared context for ${it.name} : " + it.context }

            println "*** Stats ================ "
            /** stats on the shared context */
            stats()
        }

        println "*** 6 Info to process ======== "

        /** Gather info to process (addresses)*/
        def data = MSys.model.inject([:]) { result, entity ->
            result[entity.name] = entity.address
            result
        }
        println data

        MSys.with {

            println "*** 7 ==================== "
            model.each {
                it.sayHello
                it.sayGoodBye
                it.setAddress randomAddress(it.name);
                it.sendEmail
            }

            println "*** 8 ==================== "
            println " Hello counts"
            model.each {
                def key = it.name
                def value = MSys.context[key]
                println "Counter for ${key} = ${value}"
            }
        }
        println "*** 9 ==================== "
        MSys.eachModelDo {
            sayHello
            sayGoodBye
            setAddress randomAddress(it.name);
            sendEmail
        }

    }
}

new Demo().run()

/* end of script */
```

Comment: Uau, lots of info in there to digest, I'll take a closer look during the weekend. Thanks for your input.

Comment: It's just a WIP on my side on this DSL subject and I would be very interested in your input too. BTW I recommend you to google for Paul King and Guillaume Laforge groovy DSL, you will find lot of things. :) 
TIA